# Do other elements exist?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

In season 2 of the Legend of Korra, we learn about how Wan got all four elements: Fire, Air, Water and Earth. He bargained with Lion-turtles and Raava who was with him promised that s/he would protect him.

But do other elements exist other than these four? I kind of hoped when season 3 started that Korra, being the first Avatar of a new cycle, could also develop new elements like Life, Wood, or anything else.

Comment: Wood, fire, earth, metal, and water, maybe, to go with the rest of the hokey chinoiserie?

Comment: the fifth element is love.

Comment: @phantom42 - I'm pretty sure the fifth element is Milla Jovovich.

Comment: @MissMonicaE - I learned a new word today. :)  But I don’t think it’s hokey at all. :(

Comment: This isn't really the place for "wouldn't it be cool if" types of questions.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish It says that *now* after my edit.  The original question was "Could they" not "Do they".  I made the edit to bring it back on topic.